# CPAN install module meet make file not ok issue

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to run this script on my computer (MAC)

http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color-summarizer/?download

It's the first time in my life touching the terminal... so you understand that I ask very basic questions. please do forgive me... 
basically when i execute the script, I would always get this kind of message :

```
 Can't locate Imager/File/GIF.pm in @INC (you may need to install the 
 Imager::File::GIF module) (@INC contains: 
 /Applications/colorsummarizer/colorsummarizer-0.77/bin/lib 
 /Applications/colorsummarizer/colorsummarizer-0.77/bin/../lib 
 /Applications/colorsummarizer/colorsummarizer-0.77/bin 
 /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 
 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-
 multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 
 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
 /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-
 thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18) at 
 /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Imager.pm line 1677.
```

And so I use :

```
 sudo cpan install Imager::File::GIF
```

for example. But the I get this :

```
 Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lgif
 GIF: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'gif_lib.h', 'stdio.h', 
 'errno.h', 'string.h', 'gif'
 OS unsupported: GIF libraries or headers not found
  Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
   TONYC/Imager-File-GIF-0.91.tar.gz
   /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
 Running make test
   Make had some problems, won't test
 Running make install
   Make had some problems, won't install
 Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

And ! it seems like even when I appear to install something successfully, The system ask me to re-install them again and again and again... 
Maybe I did some very fundamental mistakes ?
Thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: `cpan install` is wrong. You just installed the `install` module.

Comment: Moreover, you need the header files of the C gif library.

Comment: @melpomene thanks. but than i still got "Makefile.PL -- NOT OK" this message and I think this might be a problem ...

Comment: @choroba would you be kind enough to explain what that is please :)

Comment: Are you a programmer?

Comment: not at all ! I use R for my research, that's all ... But i need to use this script to analyse images...

Answer (score 1):

The issue identified by the following message is not harmless at all, actually:

> Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lgif
> GIF: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'gif_lib.h', 'stdio.h', 
> 'errno.h', 'string.h', 'gif'

The module uses libgif to do all the heavy work, but it's not installed. Furthermore, the installation procedure needs the library's header files.

> Imager::File::GIF provides GIF file format support for Imager.
>
> It requires libgif to be installed, including development headers.
>
> For Linux distributions this typically requires installation of the
> associated -dev or -devel package.

Installing the required library and header files might be as simple as asking your OS's package manager to install `libgif-dev` or `libgif-devel`.

Answer (score -3):

Try to just install `Imager` like this, it might be all you need:

```
 sudo cpan Imager
```

After that it could open gifs for me.

Comment: Why do you think the Imager::File::GIF isn't needed?

Comment: installing Imager::File::GIF directly also gave me the same errors, but after just installing `Imager` it opens gifs just fine! that was the objective here, thus worth a shot. @ikegami Did you try before down-voting?

Comment: Re "*Did you try before down-voting?*", Why would I? The program is trying to load one module, and you said the fix is to install a different module the OP already has installed (seeing as it's a dependency of Imager::File::GIF).

Comment: Re "*it opens gifs just fine!*", This isn't about opening GIFs with Imager; this is about running `colorsummarizer`.